# How to sort a Listview in a DataTemplate in XAML only?

Tags: xaml, sorting, listview, datatemplate

I have a window with a TabControl that i've bind to a list of objec, I'll called MyItem :

```
    <TabControl Name="MyTabPNL"  Background="Gainsboro"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemList, ElementName=WatcherWindow}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource tabItemTemplate}">
    </TabControl>
```

This MyItem class has an ObservableCollection, that I want to bind to a Listview, I'm doing this with a DataTemplate. 
GOAL: I'd like to sort automatically this ObservableCollection in XAML. Usually i would use a CollectionViewSource, but i can't find a way to this... I've tried stuff like that:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tabItemTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources> 
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key='dayList' Source="{Binding MyDayList}">
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="MyDate" Direction="Descending"  />
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>

    <Grid >
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dayList}}" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridvwDay" >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="MyDate" 
                          CellTemplate="{StaticResource myCellTemplatePNLDate}"
                          HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomHeaderStyleNeutral}" 
                           Width="70" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
   </Grid>
```

But everytime i've got the same error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot
>   find governing FrameworkElement or
>   FrameworkContentElement for target
>   element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=MyDayList;
>   DataItem=null; target element is
>   'CollectionViewSource'
>   (HashCode=58368655); target property
>   is 'Source' (type 'Object')

I can't find a way to make a link between the dayList in the ListView ItemsSource, and the dayList in the CollectionRessource. 
Do you guys have an idea?

FYI: pre sorting the ObservableCollection is not doable, because of the nature of the Class i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply,

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource dayList}">
```

As per the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx

You don't need to bind when its just static on the page :)